# i can't use RefreshIndicator with FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to use **RefreshIndicator** with **FutureBuilder** but it seems not working when I pull the refresh the data is not changing after deleting a row from database

```
RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () async {
            return await carProvider.getCar();
          },
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Car>>(
            future: carProvider.getCar(),
            // initialData: carProvider.carList,
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Car>> snapshot) {
              print(snapshot.connectionState);
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                  snapshot.data.length > 0)
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Remove'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          carProvider.removeCar(snapshot.data[index]);
                          carProvider.getCar();
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              else
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Something is wrong'),
                );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 3):

The `FutureBuilder` isn't "tied" to a method. That means that calling `carProvider.getCar()` again doesn't affect the FutureBuilder in anyway.

All it does is call the function again.

```
onRefresh: () async {
            return await carProvider.getCar();
          },
```

A much simpler way would be to just call setState to rebuild the FutureBuilder.

```
onRefresh: () async {
            setState((){});
   },
```

Comment: Thank you, but i am using provider, so i can't use setState()

Comment: Just because you’re using provider, doesn’t mean it’s wrong to use setstate.  In a lot of cases, you’ll still have to use the initstate and dispose methods. 

Provider is great for managing global state. That is, state for many different screens and widgets. If your using provider to manage a single page’s state, that just sounds like unnecessary boilerplate. In cases like that, using a simple stateful widget will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Future refresh() async{
return await carProvider.getCar();
}
```

And then:

```
RefreshIndicator(onRefresh: refresh, child: FutureBuilder(future: refresh, ....))
```

Comment: Does this update the contents of snapshot.data from the futureBuilder? I'm having trouble updating the contents from the refresh future on RefreshIndicator "onRefresh".

Comment: Yes. It does. Every time that you call that future, after it finishes it updates the content of the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually simple if used in a StatefulWidget.

1. Create a future method that returns some data eg `Future<List<String> _getLocations(){....}`
2. Declare a Future variable eg `late Future<List<String>> _futureLocations`
3. Initialize this future in `initState` method `_futureLocations = _fetchLocations();` *No await here*
4. Create a FutureBuilder with future set to `_futureLocations`
5. Create a Refresh Indicator as the parent to the above FutureBuilder
6. In the `onRefresh` method, call a simple method as follows

```
onRefresh:()async{
  setState((){
   _futureLocations = _fetchLocations();
  });
```

That's it! The above setState will trigger the FutureBuilder and it will be rebuilt with new updates.